# TSQL Query not working correctly

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have the following columns:

```
ID,  Col1, Col2, Col3,  Col4
1    Bruce Wayne Gotham City
2    Daffy Duck  Sat on the pond
3    Bruce Wayne Gotham City
```

What i need to do is select all records (ID,Col1-Col4) and display a count of how many records there are for each entry.

```
SELECT Count(*) As Counter FROM TABLE
```

but I need to use Group By in order to select the rest of the cols so :

```
SELECT (*) As Counter, ID,Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4 FROM TABLE Group By ID,Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4
```

However, this return three recods each with a count of 1 - what I'm after is two records, one with a count of 2 (Bruce Wayne) and one with a count of 1 (Daffy Duck)

** Update. ****

the results are going to be used in a C# datagrid, displaying the all four cols, i was using the ID as the link to drill down further into the record.

So the data grid would read, that I have a total of 3 records and clicking on the number would display the two separate records - so I guess i'll need something more complex than i have previously stated, because I'll need to know which ID's (as you've mentioned) link to which record.

Would I therefore need to do a nested select, getting the count first?

Comment: Remove `ID` from the `GROUP BY` and the `SELECT` or tell us which `ID` you want returned.

Comment: And which ID did you want for the row with 2 Bruce Waynes?  If you remove the ID column from your results you'll be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to select all four columns (id, col1, col2, col3) with number of records, you have to pick one of the ids from the grouped records.

For example, you can select `Min(Id)`/`Max(Id)` as below;

```
select count(*) counter, min(id) id, col1, col2, col3
from t
group by col1,col2,col3
```

[**SQL FIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/83801/9)

```
| COUNTER | ID |        COL1 |   COL2 |     COL3 |
--------------------------------------------------
|       2 |  1 | Bruce Wayne | Gotham |     City |
|       1 |  2 |  Daffy Duck | Sat on | the pond |
```

Comment: Nothing happens, What is your expected results in that situation?

Comment: ok, so let's say we have eight columns, with a possible three columns, which could and do contain the same information. the three columns in question, are messageType, MsgDate and Sender, the rest of the five columns are unique. So I need to know how many records (counter) there are for each record that contains the same MessageType, MsgDate, Sender

Comment: Number of records count depends on what you are grouping with. Here you can group with `MessageType, MsgDate, Sender` and then you can add only grouping columns (other than aggregated fields) to the select list. ie; `SELECT count(*) counter, min(id) id, MessageType, MsgDate, Sender FROM tblName GROUP BY MessageType, MsgDate, Sender`

Answer (score 0):

If you need to select all records, then use a `window` function to get the count:

```
SELECT count(*) over (partition by Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4) as Counter,
       ID,Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4
 FROM TABLE;
```

If you want only two records, then you want a group by:

```
SELECT count(*) as Counter, Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4
FROM TABLE
group by Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4
```

The `id` is unique on each row, so each group consists of one row.

Answer (score -1):

Change the order in the GROUP BY clause:

```
GROUP BY Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, ID
```

If you group by ID first, the two Bruce Wayne records are in different groups.

Comment: The order of items in the `group by` list is unimportant. A new group occurs when any of the items is different.